# How can I adapt this gmail reading code for python3? (from python)

Tags: python-3.x, email

The following code works in python2 to read gmail inbox. However it cannot be run in python3 even after I put brackets around things i need to print.

```
import smtplib
import time
import imaplib
import email

FROM_EMAIL  = "email"
FROM_PWD    = "pass"
SMTP_SERVER = "imap.gmail.com"
SMTP_PORT   = 993

mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(SMTP_SERVER)
mail.login(FROM_EMAIL,FROM_PWD)
mail.select('inbox')

type, data = mail.search(None, 'ALL')
mail_ids = data[0]

id_list = mail_ids.split()   
first_email_id = int(id_list[0])
latest_email_id = int(id_list[-1])


for i in range(latest_email_id,first_email_id, -1):
    typ, data = mail.fetch(i, '(RFC822)' )

    for response_part in data:
        if isinstance(response_part, tuple):
            msg = email.message_from_string(response_part[1])
            email_subject = msg['subject']
            email_from = msg['from']
            print('From : ' + email_from + '\n')
            print('Subject : ' + email_subject + '\n')
```

It gives me the error:

```
    data = data + b' ' + arg                                                                  
  TypeError: can't concat bytes to int
```

Comment: You are not showing the code that gives the error, how can anyone help? Provide the full stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

Two places need to be changed:

1. `typ, data = mail.fetch(str(i), '(RFC822)' )`
2. `msg = email.message_from_string(response[1].decode())`

Hope this helps.

Comment: You'll want to format those lines to look like code :)  https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help